# PHP prevent changing url slug

Tags: php, url, slug

I noticed that some sites prevent modification of the slug in the URL. For exemple in stackoverflow if you change the slug of this post, when you load the page, the real slug comes back.

This is not Javascript, so I supposed it is managed by PHP. I do not see how to do it and I really can not find any answer on the web... Anyone know ?

Comment: What matters in the SOF url is the question `id`, the `slug` part is just there for SEO purposes and can be modified as you please. In PHP you would have a route which takes note of the ID and loads pages based on this ignoring the slug part completely if you want.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not written in PHP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network), by the way.

Comment: For routing, solely depending on slug might be bad for business  apps as it will give 404 when slug changes. It will be ok for blogs or general purpose sites. Using numeric id with a optional slug should be more reliable.

Comment: @RajithaBandara If the slug is optional, then the page will be accessible by two different url, which is not a good thing for SEO. I think the best practice is to enforce the slug, and redirect if not correct.

Comment: @Lunic, yes, you 're absolutely correct. It will violate Google policies related to content duplicity. My words give a wrong idea. Sorry, my bad. Should be corrected as "use numeric id without relying on slug"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MattWritesCode notes in the comment, the important part is ID. What you can do is load the canonical slug from the database by using the ID, and if the user-provided slug does not match what you have in the database, do a redirect to the canonical ID+slug URL.

Comment: Hoo it seems so logical ! What a shame.
Thank you